# PerfectSwift: Can't compile PerfectCrypto

Tags: swift, ubuntu, perfect

I'm using PerfectSwift on Ubuntu 14.04.1, clang-3.8
I was using Perfect and all was working, but now, I can't compile anymore ( but it compiles on my mac )

Error log is

```
/home/celian/swift_server/Packages/PerfectCrypto-1.0.8/Sources/ByteIO.swift:282:43: error: cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeRawPointer?' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutableRawPointer!'
                super.init(bio: BIO_new_mem_buf(pointer.baseAddress, Int32(pointer.count)))
                                                ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/celian/swift_server/Packages/PerfectCrypto-1.0.8/Sources/ByteIO.swift:363:34: error: cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>!'
                super.init(bio: BIO_new_accept(name))
                                               ^~~~
/home/celian/swift_server/Packages/PerfectCrypto-1.0.8/Sources/ByteIO.swift:394:35: error: cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>!'
                super.init(bio: BIO_new_connect(name))
                                                ^~~~
/home/celian/swift_server/Packages/PerfectCrypto-1.0.8/Sources/OpenSSLInternal.swift:357:64: error: cannot convert value of type 'UnsafePointer<UInt8>?' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>!'
                guard 1 == EVP_DigestVerifyFinal(ctx, signature.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self), mdLen) else {
                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/openssl/bn.h:187:19: error: integer literal is too large to be represented in any integer type
#define BN_MASK         (0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffLL)
                         ^
/home/celian/swift_server/Packages/PerfectCrypto-1.0.8/Sources/OpenSSLInternal.swift:385:31: error: use of unresolved identifier 'EVP_des_ede3_wrap'
                case .des_ede3_wrap:    return EVP_des_ede3_wrap()
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/celian/swift_server/Packages/PerfectCrypto-1.0.8/Sources/OpenSSLInternal.swift:413:31: error: use of unresolved identifier 'EVP_aes_128_wrap'
                case .aes_128_wrap:             return EVP_aes_128_wrap()
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/celian/swift_server/Packages/PerfectCrypto-1.0.8/Sources/OpenSSLInternal.swift:423:31: error: use of unresolved identifier 'EVP_aes_192_wrap'
                case .aes_192_wrap:             return EVP_aes_192_wrap()
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/celian/swift_server/Packages/PerfectCrypto-1.0.8/Sources/OpenSSLInternal.swift:434:31: error: use of unresolved identifier 'EVP_aes_256_wrap'
                case .aes_256_wrap:             return EVP_aes_256_wrap()
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/celian/swift_server/Packages/PerfectCrypto-1.0.8/Sources/OpenSSLInternal.swift:437:41: error: use of unresolved identifier 'EVP_aes_128_cbc_hmac_sha256'
                case .aes_128_cbc_hmac_sha256:  return EVP_aes_128_cbc_hmac_sha256()
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
COpenSSL.EVP_aes_128_cbc_hmac_sha1:1:13: note: did you mean 'EVP_aes_128_cbc_hmac_sha1'?
public func EVP_aes_128_cbc_hmac_sha1() -> UnsafePointer<EVP_CIPHER>!
            ^
/home/celian/swift_server/Packages/PerfectCrypto-1.0.8/Sources/OpenSSLInternal.swift:438:41: error: use of unresolved identifier 'EVP_aes_256_cbc_hmac_sha256'
                case .aes_256_cbc_hmac_sha256:  return EVP_aes_256_cbc_hmac_sha256()
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
COpenSSL.EVP_aes_256_cbc_hmac_sha1:1:13: note: did you mean 'EVP_aes_256_cbc_hmac_sha1'?
public func EVP_aes_256_cbc_hmac_sha1() -> UnsafePointer<EVP_CIPHER>!
            ^
<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures
error: exit(1): /swift/usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f /home/celian/swift_server/.build/debug.yaml -v
```

My dependencies are :

```
    dependencies: [
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-HTTPServer.git", majorVersion: 2),    
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/iamjono/SwiftString.git", majorVersion: 1),
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-Curl.git", majorVersion: 2, minor: 0),
        .Package(url:"https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-XML.git", majorVersion: 2, minor: 0)

    ]
```

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Daniel added a comment - 12/Apr/17 7:43 AM
INTERNAL
Permalink Edit Delete
@Alessandro Piazza  After some research, the apparent problem is that PerfectCrypto relies on openssl 1.0.2. The official repository only has v1.0.1. I followed this instructions to install openssl v 1.0.2 https://gist.github.com/mbejda/a1dabc45b32aaf8b25ae5e8d05923518 and I was able to compile PerfectCrypto.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but don't know where I'm meant to run the .ssh you linked to. I'm running my server on google app engine so push my package.swift, main.swift, appyaml and Dockerfile with gcloud app deploy. Do you know where within that I can install openssl v1.0.2?